# Getting a compile error when trying to use class-transformer

Tags: typescript, class-transformer, reflect-metadata

I'm receiving the following error with a simple example using `class-transformer`.

```
error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'ClassFieldDecoratorContext<Root, Project[]> & { name: "Projects"; private: false; static: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.
```

Here's my example:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Type, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

class Project {
    ProjectName: string;
    ProjectDisplayName: string;
}

class Root {
    @Type(() => Project) // <- error here 
    Projects: Array<Project>;
}

function greeter(person: string) {
    return `Hello ${person}!`;
}

const greeterName = 'Node Hero'

console.log(greeter(greeterName));
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: After receiving this same error message from several different libraries which use decorators, I discovered that it's due to TypeScript 5.0 having changed the signature for decorators.

Answer (score 1):

The compile error could be sovled by appending `"experimentalDecorator": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html